# Button Menu flyout horizontal alignment in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I need to set the menuflyout to get right aligned. I used the code, but it appears at left only. Should I need to modify in the style?

```
<Button Content="Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" Width="30">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="50" />
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="50" />
                    </Style>
                </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot, it seems you are develpoing a Windows Phone 8.1 app not a UWP app.

While using UWP, your code (I remove `Height` and `Width` in the `Button`) looks like:
[image]

I think this is what you want.

But in Windows Phone 8.1, we have to modify the template of `MenuFlyoutPresenter` to achieve this.

To modify the template of `MenuFlyoutPresenter`, we can select the "**[MenuFlyout]**" in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Additional Templates**" →  "**Edit MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle**" → "**Edit a Copy...**".

In the template, we need to set the `HorizontalAlignment` of `OuterBorder`, `CenterBorder` and `InnerBorder` to `Right`:

```
<Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    ...
    <Border x:Name="CenterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel x:Name="InnerBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        ...
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Then in the `Button`, we can use code like following:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Click">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle1}" Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

It looks like:
[image]

You can also change other properties in the `Style` of `MenuFlyoutPresenter` to beautify it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you use default settings and set your `Placement` property of `MenuFlyout`, position should look fine. When I modify your code it should work properly as what you need. Yıu can check from screenshot.

```
<Button Content="Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" Width="114" Margin="0,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

[image]